# Not able to typecast from object to class:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am not able to typecast from object variable to class type variable. Getting following error:

```
*Hibernate: select osinfo0_.host_id as host_id1_17_0_, osinfo0_.os_build as os_build2_17_0_, osinfo0_.os_name as os_name3_17_0_, osinfo0_.os_type as os_type4_17_0_, osinfo0_.os_version as os_versi5_17_0_ from hwi.os_info osinfo0_ where osinfo0_.host_id=?
Jun 15, 2015 10:28:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/HardwareInventory] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.vmware.hwi.model.StorageInfo] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.vmware.hwi.model.StorageInfo
    at com.vmware.hwi.dao.impl.StorageInfoDaoImpl.getStorageInfoFullListByTeam(StorageInfoDaoImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)*
```

I am novice to Hibernate Query writing, so I doubt there might be some mistake in writing the query, but I can see the values returned by query are completely fine, not sure where I am missing here.

Here is the part of the code:

```
@Override
public StorageInfo getStorageInfoFullListByTeam(Integer storageTeam){
    StorageInfo storageFullList = null;
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    /*Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from Host host, StorageInfo storage ServerStorage" +
            " server where storage.storageId=server.storageId" +
            " AND server.hostId=host.hostId AND storage.storageTeam= ' "
            + storageTeam+ " ' ");*/
    Query query = session.createQuery(
            "from Host host, StorageInfo storage , ServerStorage" +
            " server where storage.storageId=server.storageId" +
            " AND server.hostId=host.hostId AND storage.storageTeam= ' "
            + storageTeam + " ' ");
    List info = query.list();
    if(info.size() !=0){
        storageFullList = (StorageInfo) info.get(0);
    }
    return storageFullList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your query it looks like you are fetching Host , StorageInfo  , ServerStorage and while getting the Object (StorageInfo) info.get(0) you are trying to cast it into only StorageInfo.
So try removing Host and Serverstorage from your query or else if you want to fetch records from 3 tables create a java pojo class which represents the kind of columns that you're fetching in the query and map your pojo class(try searching mapping pojo to hibernate query results).